# Finding a relative element in jQuery Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Edit:

Rephrasing question,

So basically let's say I have two jQuery elements, **not from the dom**, and by having a sub element from one of the two, I need to find it in the other.

```
var firstDiv = '<div><div id="test"><b>Something here</b><b>I want this 
element from here</b></div></div>';
var secondDiv = '<div><div id="test"><b>Something here</b><b>I want this element from here</b></div></div>';

var firstElement = $($.parseHTML(firstDiv));
var secondElement = $($.parseHTML(secondDiv));

var wantedFromSecond = secondElement.find("#test").eq(0).find("b").eq(1);
//Pretend we don't know how we got the "wantedFromSecond" element

alert(secondElement.index(wantedFromSecond[0]));
```

Also here:

https://jsfiddle.net/338h3qk9/1/

Assume as I sad, we don't know where wantedFromSecond is from. So please don't use anything like $("#test") or such. It also isn't coming from the actual dom, so everything has to be from firstElement or secondElement.

I hope that explains it well, you can also just run the JFiddle and you'll see what I mean.

Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe the code you have is not clear but if you already have it from B is it enough to check if it exists in A? Since you already have it. Or you mean you want to get from A the 2nd <b> child of #test?

Comment: You should move your Fiddle code into your question.

Comment: @Soviut , I updated my question

Comment: I've written a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the element into a selector and simply find it in the document.

```js
// find in the entire document
$('<b>I want this element from here</b>');

// find in specific element
$('#test').find('b:contains("I want this element from here")');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="test">
    <b>Something here</b>
    <b>I want this element from here</b>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="test2">
    <b>Something else here</b>
    <b>I want this element from here</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would happen though if the content for both bold tags were 'I want this element from here'?

Comment: If you're searching the entire document, it will find both. However, I included an example showing a more specific find that only looks inside the first element.

Comment: That means if the content is the same for both <b>'s, then the code wouldn't work

Comment: If you take a look at my updated edit, it has a JSFiddle of what I'm trying to do, but can't :)

Comment: Why do you have two answers? Could you maybe delete one

Comment: @Canvas because the question has evolved. They're both relevant and it'll be up to the OP to decide which one accept.

Comment: @Soviut you should state that and move your first answer in to this answer

Comment: @Canvas that would complicate things too much and dilute both answers. Having two answers isn't a problem since they address different aspects of the question. Again, it'll be up to the OP to decide which one to accept, but having both won't be an issue.

Comment: @Soviut Okidoki

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSFiddle, you're using `.index()` incorrectly. You're using it on the top-level `<div>` element from your imported HTML. You need to drill down to the elements you need and then perform the index.

```js
var firstDiv = '<div><div id="test"><b>Something here</b><b>I want this element from here</b></div></div>';
var secondDiv = '<div><div id="test"><b>Something here</b><b>I want this element from here</b></div></div>';

var firstElement = $($.parseHTML(firstDiv));
var secondElement = $($.parseHTML(secondDiv));

var wantedFromSecond = secondElement.find("#test").find("b").eq(1);

// use a selector specific enough to only get the <b> elements, then index those
console.log(secondElement.find('#test b').index(wantedFromSecond)));

// the following won't work because you're using index on the top level element
//console.log(secondElement.index(wantedFromSecond));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```